# Marker icon image duplication

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have two images: small for default marker state and big for selected.

After tapping on marker, I'm changing marker icons for new state, but sometimes I see that small icon is placed over big icon. I thought it should be updated with `tracksViewChanges` property, but it doesn't.

You can see green marker on image, which have big icon under small.

My code is simple:

```objective-c
-(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    if (self.lastMarker) {
        Car *lastCar = (Car*)self.lastMarker.userData;
        self.lastMarker.icon = [lastCar.provider smallPinIcon];
    }

    Car *car = (Car*)marker.userData;

    marker.tracksViewChanges = YES;
    marker.icon = [car.provider bigPinIcon];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:^{

    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        marker.tracksViewChanges = NO;
    }];
    self.lastMarker = marker;


    GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];

    bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:self.userMarker.position];
    bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position];

    GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(120, 60, 120, 60)];

    [self.mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:update];


    return YES;
```

}

Methods `smallPinIcon` and `bigPinIcon` caching actual images.

This is Google Maps SDK bug or I'm doing something wrong?

[image: map with marker]